# Ajuda com campo para guardar um link

Tags: mysql, link, varchar

Preciso guardar um link no banco de dados, que no caso é MySQL, eu estava utilizando VARCHAR(255), mas notei facilmente alguns dos links armazenados ultrapassava 255 caracteres, que tipo de dado posso usar no banco pra armazenar essa informação? acredito que deva suportar até uns 400 caracteres, pra garantir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/1518921), então *2048* tem que ser o máximo para buscadores, então creio que 400 é bem pouco, creio que este seja o minimo.

Então execute:

```mysql
ALTER TABLE `tabela` CHANGE `coluna` `coluna` varchar(2048) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Só uma observação, se não tiver nenhuma razão pra cortar em 2048, definir como 64k gasta exatamente o mesmo espaço no db (+ conteúdo real). Até 65535 bytes são gastos apenas 2 bytes a mais do que o próprio conteúdo. Mais que isso, só se for TEXT

Comment: @Bacco Verdade, boa!